# Is there an Idle callback function for JOGL (Java OGL)?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I've noticed that functions don't have to be registered, as the normal callbacks are included in the GLEventListener interface. However I can't seem to find glutIdleFunc() as a method of the GLUT class, or anything on the internet to indicate an alternative (as of yet). Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Please indicate what you would like to put into such a "callback". There is nothing similar in JOGL but it's not necessary. The documentation says that " not more than a single frame of rendering should be done in an idle callback": https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node63.html Then, you can just call your code in the method GLEventListener.display(). What is wrong with that?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in JOGL called an "idle callback" like what GLUT has. The idea of the idle callback is to run something when the events are done processing (resize, keypress, etc). People usually used it to render new frames.

The similar concept in JOGL is GLEventListener. These are callbacks to draw frames. You ask (or tell) JOGL to render frames at a certain rate and it will invoke your event listener.